# python parse string into individual chararcters

Tags: python, string, parsing, format, character

In Python 2.7 how do I parse 'abc' into 'a b c' for a very long string (like 1000 chars)?

Or how would I convert 'abccda' to '1 2 3 3 4 1'? (where each unique letter maps to a unique digit, 1-4)

I imagine I could pop the chars off, one by one, but I'm new to Python and wonder if there is a simple function that does it.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Try to focus on one clear question at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the first one use `join()`:

```
>>> s = 'abc'
>>> ' '.join(s)
'a b c'
```

For the second one:

```
>>> s = 'abccda'
>>> ' '.join(chr(ord(c)-ord('a')+ord('1')) for c in s)
'1 2 3 3 4 1'
```

or you could simply use a dictionary to map letters to numbers:

```
>>> s = 'abccda'
>>> d = dict(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4)
>>> ' '.join(str(d[c]) for c in s)
'1 2 3 3 4 1'
```

And yet another way is to use `string.translate()`:

```
>>> from string import maketrans
>>> s = 'abccda'
>>> ' '.join(s.translate(maketrans('abcd', '1234')))
'1 2 3 3 4 1'
```

`translate()` would be the preferred one since, as opposed to the naive dict lookup, it handles unmapped characters without errors:

```
>>> s='abcdefgh'
>>> ' '.join(s.translate(maketrans('abcd', '1234')))
'1 2 3 4 e f g h'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x="abc"
print re.sub(r"(?<!^)(.)",r" \1",x)
```

For simple conversion you can try this.For mapping you can define you `repl`function in `re.sub`.An example can be

```
def repl(matchobj):
    if matchobj.group()=='b':
         return " "+str(1)
    elif matchobj.group()=='c':
         return " "+str(2)
x="abc"
print re.sub(r"(?<!^)(.)",repl,x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the list method?

s='abccda'

list(s)   # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'a']

Answer (score 1):

To convert each letter into a number, you can use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate). This is probably overkill in this simple case, but it's worth learning.

The details are different in Python 2 and Python 3.

For Python 3, you can just use a mapping from Unicode ordinals to replacement strings, like this:

```
mapping = {ord(letter): str(number) for number, letter in enumerate(string.ascii_lowercase[:4], 1)}
translated = x.translate(mapping)
```

For Python 2, you need a special translation table, which in this case is a little less convenient (and will only let you translate characters to single characters, not to arbitrary strings like the Python 3 version—not a problem here, but if you wanted to convert `'j'` to `'10`' it wouldn't work):

```
mapping = string.maketrans(string.ascii_lowercase[:4], 
                           ''.join(str(i) for i in range(1, 5))
translated = x.translate(mapping)
```

Then, to add spaces, use [mhawke's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27539906/908494):

```
result = ' '.join(translated)
```